# Get max and min length values and data of columns?

Tags: linux

In a tab separated file with 10 fields, how can I get the min and max length of a field and the data values like below:

```
Field1 : Min 5 max 10  abcde abcdefghij
Field2: Min 3 max 5    abc   abcde
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input

Answer (score 2):

The following script should accomplish what you need:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

input=./input
row=0
while read -r line; do
    columns=( $line )
    ((row++))
    max=0
    min=${#line}
    vmax=
    vmin=
    for column in "${columns[@]}"; do
        ((${#column}>max)) && max=${#column} && vmax=$column
        ((${#column}<min)) && min=${#column} && vmin=$column
    done
    echo "Row${row}: Min $min max $max $vmin $vmax"
done<"$input"
```

Given this input:

```
field0      field1     field2    field3   field4  field5  field6   field7    field8     field9
a           aa         aaa       aaaa     aaaaa   aaaaaa  aaaaaaa  aaaaaaaa  aaaaaaaaa  aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb  bbbbbbbbb  bbbbbbbb  bbbbbbb  bbbbbb  bbbbb   bbbb     bbb       bb         b
```

It will produce this output:

```
$ ./script.sh
Row1: Min 6 max 6 field0 field0
Row2: Min 1 max 10 a aaaaaaaaaa
Row3: Min 1 max 10 b bbbbbbbbbb
```

Note:  If a row has multiple fields of the same length that end up being the min/max length row it will output the first field of that length.  (In the example input row1 has all equal length fields so it listed field0 as both min and max).